# Custom user fields validation on registration

Tags: customization, forms, user-registration

I am using the 'wpestate' theme for my website but I would like to add some custom fields for my user registration. So I tried the following code to extend it:

The probelem:
When I try to register a new account it seems the page is doing only a page refresh that's it. It's no problem that it is not working with AJAX currently but a normal registration would be nice.

This is the logic to validate a few fields.. But I think it never goes in there.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Ajax  Register function
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_register_form', 'ajax_register_form' );
  // add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_register_form', 'ajax_register_form' );

function ajax_register_form(){

        //check_ajax_referer( 'register_ajax_nonce','security-register');

        $user_email  =   trim( $_POST['user_email_register'] ) ;

        ///echo $user_email;
        $user_name   =   trim( $_POST['user_email_register'] ) ;
        $firstname   =   trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) ;
        $lastname   =   trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) ;
        $street   =   trim( $_POST['rpr_street'] ) ;
        $number  =   trim( $_POST['rpr_number'] ) ;
        $city   =   trim( $_POST['rpr_city'] ) ;
        $country   =   trim( $_POST['rpr_country'] ) ;
        $phone   =   trim( $_POST['rpr_phone'] ) ;

    if ($user_email=='' || $lastname == '' || $firstname =='' || $street == '' || $number == '' || $city == '' || $city == '' || $country == '' || $phone == ''){
            print __('All fields are required.', 'wpestate');
            exit();
        }


        if(filter_var($user_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
             print __('The email doesn\'t look right !','wpestate');
            exit();
        }

        $domain = substr(strrchr($user_email, "@"), 1);
        if( !checkdnsrr ($domain) ){
            print __('The email\'s domain doesn\'t look right.','wpestate');
            exit();
        }


        $user_id     =   email_exists( $user_email );
        if ($user_id){
            print __('Username already exists.  Please choose a new one.','wpestate');
            exit();
         }



        if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {



            $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );

            $user_id  = wp_create_user( $user_email, $random_password, $user_email );

             if ( is_wp_error($user_id) ){
                    print_r($user_id);
             }else{
                   print __('Your account is waiting for approval, you will receive a mail once your account is approved by Sophima.','wpestate');
                   wpestate_update_profile($user_id);
                   wpestate_wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $random_password ) ;
                   if('yes' ==  esc_html ( get_option('wp_estate_user_agent','') )){
                    wpestate_register_as_user($user_name,$user_id);
                   }
             }

        } else {
           print __('Email already exists.  Please choose a new one.','wpestate');
        }


        die(); 

}
```

This is the part where I generate the form fields:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// register form  function
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/**
 * @param $attributes
 * @param null $content
 * @return string
 *
 *  <div class="row">
<label for="user_login">'.__('Username','wpestate').'</label>
<input type="text" name="user_login_register" id="user_login_register" class="input" value="" size="20" />
</div>

 */
function register_form_function($attributes, $content = null) {


     $return_string='
     <form action="" method="POST">
          <div class="login_form">
               <div class="loginalert" id="register_message_area" ></div>


                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="first_name">'.__('Firstname','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="last_name">'.__('Lastname','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="user_email">'.__('Email','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="user_email_register" id="user_email_register" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                <div class="row">
                        <label for="rpr_street">'.__('Street','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rpr_street" id="rpr_street" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="rpr_number">'.__('Number','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rpr_number" id="rpr_number" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                <div class="row">
                        <label for="rpr_city">'.__('City','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rpr_city" id="rpr_city" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="rpr_country">'.__('Country','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rpr_country" id="rpr_country" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>

                 <div class="row">
                        <label for="rpr_phone_number">'.__('Phone number','wpestate').'</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rpr_phone_number" id="rpr_phone_number" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                 </div>




                <p id="reg_passmail">'.__('A password will be e-mailed to you','wpestate').'</p>

                '. wp_nonce_field( 'register_ajax_nonce', 'security-register' ).'   
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit-register" class="btn vernil small" value="'.__('Register','wpestate').'" /></p>

        </div>

     </form>

    ';
     return  $return_string;
}
```

Thanks a lot! For every assistance.

Comment: The ajax_register_form() function is only hooked to an ajax-request, so the form data is not processed with a regular submit, only if the ajax works. I would suggest you to fix the ajax form submission first, or else you need to edit the ajax_register_form function to work with regular forms which would take more effort to do in my opinion. You can test it by changing the first add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_register_form'... line to add_action( 'init'..., this will submit your form properly, but make sure you have a conditional logic in your function so it won't run always

Comment: And please, also fix your code (empty lines, indentation) as it's close to unreadable in its current state.